# Explicitly providing nrow and ncol to `as.matrix` does not create dimensions

Tags: r, matrix

I am creating a simple 3x3 matrix with 9 values using the as.matrix() function. But the output I am seeing seems to be incorrect. What am I missing?

Here's what I am doing:

```
> s <- as.matrix(c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),nrow = 3,ncol = 3)
```

What I expect to see:

```
> s
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    4    7   10
[3,]    5    8   11
```

But What I actually see:

```
> s
      [,1]
 [1,]    3
 [2,]    4
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    6
 [5,]    7
 [6,]    8
 [7,]    9
 [8,]   10
 [9,]   11
>
```

What am I missing?

The documentation for as.matrix() function says that nrow and ncol are used to defined the ***desired number of rows and columns***.
Any pointers?

Comment: To reiterate what @RonakShah said, if you look as the documentation for `as.matrix` vs. simply `matrix`, you will see that their API is different. `matrix` takes the arguments you have in your example (i.e. `nrow` and `ncol`) however `as.matrix` has the ellipsis `...` as its second argument which are "additional arguments to be passed to or from methods".

Answer (score 4):

`as.matrix` has no `nrow` and `ncol` parameter. What you need is actually `matrix`. Check `?as.matrix`

```
matrix(c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),nrow = 3,ncol = 3) 

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    6    9
#[2,]    4    7   10
#[3,]    5    8   11
```

Comment: Thank you. I re read the documentation and you're right. The nrow and ncol arguments are for the matrix() function and not the as.matrix() function. That explains.

Answer (score 3):

You offered a vector as the first argument to `as.matrix` and the help page (`Details` section) says:

> The default method for `as.matrix` calls `as.vector(x)`, and hence e.g. coerces factors to character vectors.
>
> When coercing a vector, it produces a one-column matrix, and promotes the names (if any) of the vector to the rownames of the matrix.

The usage section doesn't actually include `ncol` or `nrow` in the argument list to `as.matrix`. They just get ignored. The code to look at is:

```
as.matrix.default
```

That code does preserve matrix dimension if the first argument has them.

I find that using `as.matrix` is a good way to get `print` to produce a left-justified one column listing of atomic character vectors.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I realized that the documentation clearly mentions nrow and ncol for the matrix() function and not the as.matrix() function.